Identify 80's computer education show
This was a show I saw on TV in the early 80s. Each episode two kids would go visit their next door neighbor who taught them (and the audience) basic computer concepts.

Computer guy was bearded and had tons of home computers and other stuff in his garage.
Memorably, he also owned a Heathkit HERO 1 robot.
Show was in English, and almost certainly American.
Opening sequence has lyrics that go something like this: "Follow me. Down the street. There's somebody you've got to meet. It's a brand new world." 


Could it have possibly been Whiz Kids? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whiz_Kids_(TV_series)

@DustinDavis - No I know that show, and it's not it. But they did air at roughly the same period.

Here's a guess: Mr. Microchip
From TVarchive.ca, a short summary:

Mr. Microchip was CBC's first formal venture into programming about
  computers for children. A show to be shared by parents with children,
  its aim was to demystify computers and their functions. 
With Skip Lumley, a computer business consultant, neighbours Dayna Simon and Steve Grosfield learned about and worked with computers in
  Lumley's garage. Each program was devoted to one aspect of computer
  functions. An attempt was made to put computers in their proper social
  and human context. 
As the series progressed, the audience learned, along with the kids,
  how computers worked, how to tell them what to do, how computers'
  brains compared with people's, where computers were used, and how they
  could help us.

From WorldCat, here's an episode guide:

Episode 1: Information please
Mr. Microchip presents an overview of computers. He explains how
  computers work, and how they can be used to solve problems, design
  objects, and monitor operations. Basic computer terms are defined, and
  home systems are differentiated from professional systems.

Episode 2: Bits of programming
Mr. Microchip discusses how the programs become more complex as the
  computer grows in complexity. He also defines and describes
  "upgrading" of computer systems.

Episode 3: Memory is made of this
Mr. Microchip explains the various types of computer memory (RAM, ROM,
  floppy disk). He discusses how information is put into the computer
  memory, and clarifies the differences between human memory
  (associative) and the computer's perfect memory.

Episode 4: The computer has a code
Mr. Microchip gives an introduction about talking a computer's
  language. He explains how information is stored via a binary code, and
  the different languages in use, especially BASIC, the most widely
  used.

Episode 5: Problems, problems, problems
Mr. Microchip explains how the computer solves problems. He discusses
  how the computer uses information and follows certain rules, and
  whether or not computers can make mistakes.

A total of 13 episodes were aired. You can read about those using the WorldCat link above. 
Here's the biggest (!) snap of the host I could find. Mr. Lumley seems to fit your description, but I've no clue if he sported a beard back in the 80s!

I also haven't come across anything to confirm whether or not the HERO 1 robot appeared on this show. Will add more information as soon as I do.

Wow! That looks pretty close to what I remember! I'll do some more research on this and confirm, but it's looking good!

No other pics or vids that I can find, but the episodes description definitely ring a bell. By Jove I think you've got it! I have to ask, how in the world did you manage to find it?

I couldn't find any related media either. A search on Google Books turned up a few leads. You can go through them here, here and here. I didn't include those in my answer for obvious reasons :-) You could try contacting the Canadian Television Archive or CBC. Who knows? Maybe they'll be nice and share some videos. Keep me posted.

Regarding your other question... Actually, CBC/TVO-related sites are good places to look for obscure 70s and 80s shows. You'll find a lot of stuff that aired on PBS and local cable channels during that time. I don't know how or why - it just is :-)

Mr. Wizard's World fits most of the criteria, except having a beard. He had the robot and taught things from electronics and science. The show ran from 1983-1990/1 on Nickelodeon.

I am aware of the late great Mr. Wizard. It's not his show. The show I'm looking for was only about computers.
